# How to make a file manager delete files?

Tags: java, android, file-manager

I am trying to make a file manager delete files from sdcard. There is only one path "/sdcard/Soundcast/" and I want to be able to delete files from it which are .mp4 and .3gp. Here's my code:

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{

```
private List<String> items =null;

private void deleteFile()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getFiles(new File("/sdcard/Soundcast").listFiles()); }
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{ int selectedRow = (int)id; if (selectedRow == 0)
    { getFiles(new File("/sdcard/Soundcast").listFiles()); }
    else
    { File file = new File(items.get(selectedRow)); if (file.isDirectory())
        { getFiles(file.listFiles()); }
        else
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) .setTitle("Ability to open files will come in future updates.")
            .setMessage("Do You Want To Delete this recording?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button){
                    deleteFile();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button){
                }
            }).show();}
            }
            }
private void getFiles(File[] files)
{ items = new ArrayList<String>();

    items.add(getString(R.string.goto_root)); for (File file : files)
    { items.add(file.getPath()); }

    ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.file_list_row, items);
    setListAdapter(fileList); } }
```

Comment: What's the question again? What have you tried? Is it just an implementation for your `deleteFile()` method, you need?

Comment: This what I have tried so far. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Waza_Be already states, all you need is file.delete(). So just delete your deleteFile method and instead of invoking it (in the onClick method of the positive dialog button), simply call file.delete() and you're done:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
    // deleteFile();     <-- not needed
    file.delete();   //  <-- do this instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use that code, or something similar:

```
{ File file = new File(items.get(selectedRow)); if (file.isDirectory())
    { getFiles(file.listFiles()); }
    else
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this) .setTitle("Ability to open files will come in future updates.")
        .setMessage("Do You Want To Delete this recording?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button){
                booolean success = file.delete()
                //Refresh UI and your list, so the deleted file is no more diplayed
            }
        })
```

And filtering by extension is not really complicated..

I don't understand where is your problem..

Comment: I was trying to delete any file on click with extensions .mp4 and .3gp. When clicked it would show a dialog asking to delete the file, with buttons yes and no, and when clicking yes it would delete it.

Comment: So you want to explain how to create a dialog with 2 buttons? We already explained how to delete the file... Nobody here really gets where you need support...